# Crop out old page numbering and add new page numbering while using pdfpages

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I'm using the pdfpages package to insert pages from existing pdfs into my tex file. I want to override the page numbering on the pdf pages I'm inserting.

Below is an image of what is happening in terms of page numbering when I use

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{filename}
```

The original page numbering is "0", and the page number being added by pdfpages is "3". I'd like for the "3" to be the only number that shows up.

---

[image]

---

Edit:
Thanks for all the help!

Below is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand{\ip}[1]{\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},clip, 
  trim=5mm 37mm 5mm 20mm]{#1.pdf}}

\begin{document}

\ip{d}
\ip{g}
\ip{h}

\end{document}
```

[Example PDF](http://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes03/h.pdf). Also, is there a way to replace the cropped out part with dummy space, shift the document upward, or lower the page numbering? Otherwise, the page numbering is appearing over the text.

Comment: You probably just need to trim off the original page numbers. You can pass `includepdf` the `clip` and `trim` options that apply to the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: Welcome! Cropping seems the way to go, as suggested already. If you need further help, please provide code for a minimal document we can compile to produce the output you want help with. A picture of your output alone isn't much help. A complete but minimal example is much more useful than mere fragments of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the solution here is to trim the existing page numbers. The original page size is restored using the `pdfpages` key `templatesize`. Checking the properties of the example pdf file tells us that its size is 215.9mm x 279.4mm.

We can restore page numbers using `\pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}`. However, the default page number position overwrites the text at the bottom of page 2. Therefore, the new page numbers are produced using a customized footer and the `fancyhdr` package:

```
\newcommand{\myfooter}{%
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\vspace{1cm}\thepage} }
```

The footer is invoked using `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Needed for customized footer

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt} % Eliminate rule in header
\newcommand{\myfooter}{              % Place the page number 1cm below default position
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\vspace{1cm}\thepage}
}

\includepdfset{                      % Setup keys for calls of \includepdf
    pages=-,
    templatesize={215.9mm}{279.4mm}, % Because the page gets trimmed reset the page size
    nup=1x1,
    scale=1,
    clip, 
    trim=5mm 36.5mm 5mm 20mm,        % Trim off the exisitng page numbers
    fitpaper=true,
    pagecommand={\myfooter}          % Apply the customized page numbering
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{example} % Example pdf supplied by OP

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that only options specific to pdfpages can be made global by `\includepdfset`. Since `trim` and `clip` are options of the graphicx package, these need to be included in each call, e.g. `\includepdf[trim = {5mm 36.5mm 5mm 20mm}, clip = true]{example}`. Not sure if that's new, but this made the example work for me.

Comment: Great solution, just noting for others that you can find the document size in the properties (as you mention) using `pdfinfo`, which is likely to be installed on any system with latex set up.